# Chaning the order of output layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have build CNN using keras.

My output is in shape:

```
[[a1,b1,c1,d1],
 [a2,b2,c2,d2],
 [a3,b3,c3,d3]
]
```

However is there a way how to rearrange the output layer so the output will be

```
[[a2,b2,c2,d2],
 [a1,b1,c1,d1],
 [a3,b3,c3,d3]
]
```

Given, that i already have the former output? The CNN output the first example, then i want it to rearange the output the second example.

my CNN ends with

```
x = Conv2D(1024, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_22', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_22')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(15 * 4, activation='relu')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
x = Reshape((15, 4), name='predictions')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caution:** Be aware that the model will always compare input1 with ouput1; input2 with output2; and so on. This is Keras behavior that cannot be changed.

You can reorder the first dimension with `K.gather()`.

```
import keras.backend as K

reorder = [1,0,2] #the order of the indices, according to your example

reorderingLayer = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(x,reorder))
```

Comment: thats what i am trying to achieve, to compare input1 with output2, i want to put output1 to first position so it can be compared - Did u mean that when i reorder the output, next iteration will wil be compared outpu2 to input1 bcs output2 is on first position? Or otherwise

Comment: Do you want to change the order in every iteration?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is following: calculate IOU for every combination of output/input (labels). Then if for example output2 has the biggest IOU with input1, move output2 to first position so the next iteration output2 would get compared to input1

Comment: That's a whole new question then..... you should do that with numpy only, outside of the model. Create the loops and iterations yourself and use only one epoch in the fit method. (Or even `model.train_on_batch`, if you have only one batch -> data.length == batch_size)

Comment: Currently what i am doing is similliar, i do it with INPUT, but i would like to try it with output as well, i calculate IOU , then rearange input to match the output. However this seems to produce weird result , my CNN can only learn how to find max 2 objects ( they are not 100% found but 2 boxes are found )